# Delete multiple string left in [Delphi]

Tags: delphi

Hello I need a simple function to delete left text strings, see the example below:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: string;
begin
  S := 'Hello test test test [delimitator] goodby.. test teest test';
  Delete(S, Pos('[delimitator]', S), MaxInt);
  RichEdit1.Text := S;
end;
```

This function clears all the characters on the right, even if I don't know how many characters there are.

The question is, how to do the reverse, to delete all the characters on the left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know what to use - `Pos()` and `Delete()`. Just tweak *how* you use them:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: string;
begin
  S := 'Hello test test test [delimitator] goodby.. test teest test';
  Delete(S, 1, Pos('[delimitator]', S));
  RichEdit1.Text := S;
end;
```

Comment: Maybe add code to handle the case where delimiter is not found.

Comment: @fpiette if the delimiter is not found, `Pos()` will return 0, and so `Delete(S, 1, 0)` won't delete anything. This actually works better when deleting in the left than the right, where 0 would have to be handled special to avoid clearing the whole string.

Answer (score -2):

You might use the following function to get this done.

```pascal
Function GetRightPart(InputString, Delimiter : String) : String;
VAR
  HelpArr   : TArray<String>;
begin
   HelpArr := InputString.Split([Delimiter]) ;
   Result  := HulpArr[1];
end;
```

Comment: What happens if `Delimiter` isn't found in `InputString`? (And why no `const` on the string parameters?)

Comment: It is just fine to enter any string value. Nothing happens with it. Of course yoe need to test whether the delimiter exists before calling the routine. If the delimiter occurs more than once then the result will be only the part between the first and the second delimiter.

Comment: JGMS: It shouldn't be that easy to misuse the function and get an AV. IMHO, a function like this *must* make sure that `HelpArr[1]` exists before it is accessing it. Quality software has both belts and braces -- everywhere, at every level.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to everyone's help. This is not very professional, but I came to that conclusion, which can be used separately or together.

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  left_delimitator,
  right_delimitator: integer;
  get_left, get_right,
  left_dbg, right_dbg: string;
begin
  RichEdit1.Clear;

  get_left  := 'test 123 [delimitator] all string left deleted.';
  get_right := 'all string rigth deleted. [delimitator] test 123';

  left_delimitator := Pos('[delimitator]', get_left);
  if left_delimitator > 0 then
  begin
    Delete(get_left, 1, Pos('[delimitator]', get_left));
    left_dbg := '[' + get_left;
    RichEdit1.Lines.Add( left_dbg );
  end;

  right_delimitator := Pos('[delimitator]', get_right);
  if right_delimitator > 0 then
  begin
    Delete(get_right, Pos('[delimitator]', get_right), MaxInt);
    right_dbg := '[delimitator]' + ' ' + get_right;
    RichEdit1.Lines.Add( right_dbg );
  end;
end;
```

Comment: When you call `Pos()` to find a substring and save its position to a variable, don’t call `Pos()` again to find the same position again. Use the variable you already have. `Delete(get_left, 1, Pos(‘[delimitator]’, get_left));` should be `Delete(get_left, 1, left_delimitator);` and likewise `Delete(get_right, Pos(‘[delimitator]’, get_right), MaxInt);` should be `Delete(get_right, right_delimitator, MaxInt);`